# Convert AES-128-CBC PHP to JAVA

Tags: java, php, encryption

I have program encrypt/decrypt using PHP and want to replace it with JAVA programming.

I have tried to convert but somehow the result didn't the same. have been searching in google and this forum for this problem but the result not match.

Here's the code PHP:

```
    protected function aes_encode($plain_text) {
    $secret_key = 'TWOFC_ODSACCOUNT';
    $ivBytes = chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0);
    return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plain_text, "AES-128-CBC", $secret_key, true, $ivBytes));
}
```

---

```
$plain_text: {"test":"aaaaa"}
Output : /BjE8Fmwcok7rBtD1pdYOO2YkHic7nqXAQQ1/SAsFF8=
```

---

Here's the code JAVA:

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES";
private static final byte[] SALT = "TWOFC_ODSACCOUNT".getBytes();

static String getEncrypted(String plainText) {
    if (plainText == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Key salt = getSalt();

    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, salt);
        byte[] encodedValue = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedValue);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to encrypt data");
}

static Key getSalt() {
    return new SecretKeySpec(SALT, ALGORITHM);
}
```

---

```
 Output : /BjE8Fmwcok7rBtD1pdYOL6iFK9jqAYS86tEAbA/+io=
```

Comment: First of all in java for *AES-128-CBC* you need to use `AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING` algorithm. Second, in `cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, salt);` you'll need to pass IV as third argument

Comment: thank you for replies, here's the code ,  the resutlt is not correct.
        static final String initVector = "0000000000000000";
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
       SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(SALT, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,iv);
 byte[] encodedValue = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
 return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedValue);

output : Ui8Bdg3SpR6RPcJTY/VkxXOgo65YkeV27kYlc9ctIJ4=

Comment: You must use `IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);`. Note that a static IV like a zero IV is insecure. In the PHP code, `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` should be used as the 4th parameter instead of `true`.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the ciphertext starts the same. That usually means that there is a problem with the padding of the final block, or that the mode is incorrect, or both.

Currently you are using `"AES"` as algorithm. This commonly defaults to `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`. What you would need is `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` for normal CBC operation. You should provide an all zero IV to be compliant with the PHP code.

It might be that the `true` parameter in the PHP / `openssl_encrypt` results in `ZERO_PADDING` being triggered for the call. In that case you should manually create a zero padding. That means adding zeros to the plaintext or last (partial) plaintext block until the number of plaintext bytes is a multiple of the block size. You should remove the zero bytes after decryption as well. And in that case you'd of course use `"AES/CBC/NoPadding"` instead.