# function fsockopen equivalient in JAVA

Tags: java, php, https

Continue to this question [Convert AES-128-CBC PHP to JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206180/convert-aes-128-cbc-php-to-java) to migrate code for PHP to Java Programming, I faced the issue how to replace fsockopen in Java.

Here's the PHP code :

```
  $sockHost = 'https://xxxx';
  $port = '443'
  $getPath = 'xxxx/xxx'
  $getHost = 'xxx'
  $data 'paramxxx'   
  $sock = fsockopen($sockHost, $port, $errNo, $errStr, 1000.0);

    if ($sock == true) {
        fwrite($sock, "POST " . $getPath . " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
        fwrite($sock, "Host: " . $getHost() . "\r\n");
        fwrite($sock, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        fwrite($sock, 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data) . "\r\n");
        fwrite($sock, "Connection:close\r\n\r\n");
        fwrite($sock, $data);


        while (feof($sock) == false) {
             $result .= fread($sock, 256);
        }

        fclose($sock);
```

Here's Java Code:

```
private static void connect(String data,String host){
    String https_url = "https://xxxx";
    String host = "xxx";
    String data= "xxx";
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection https_con = getHttpsClient(https_url);
        https_con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length()));
        https_con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        https_con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        https_con.setRequestProperty("Host",host);
        https_con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        https_con.setRequestProperty("Data",data);
        https_con.setDoOutput(true);
        https_con.connect();

        int responseCode = https_con.getResponseCode();
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(https_con.getInputStream()))) {
            String line;
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
        https_con.disconnect();



    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static HttpsURLConnection getHttpsClient(String url) throws Exception {

    // Security section START
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }};

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    // Security section END

    HttpsURLConnection client = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    //add request header
    client.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36");
    return client;
}
```

But the output write all of the content of site, not the result of sending request to https.

Answer (score 2):

- fsockopen(PHP) is function working at TCP level while HttpsURLConnection(Java) is working at HTTP level ( https://networkinterview.com/http-vs-tcp-know-the-difference )
- The equivalent feature in java should be Socket class, pls check at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(addr);
    Socket socket = new Socket('xxxx', 443);
   String path = "/xxxx";

   // Send headers
   BufferedWriter wr =
     new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
   wr.write("POST "+path+" HTTP/1.1rn");
   wr.write("Host "+addr+" rn");
   wr.write("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedrn");
   wr.write("Content-Length: "+data.length()+"rn");
    wr.write("Connection:closernrn");

Output : You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL